# Can I sell a ship that I bought by mistake?

Tags: destiny

I recently purchased a ship that I bought by mistake. I was interested in the Kestrel Class OXO. I went to view the details of the Phaeton Class V3.1 and accidentally purchased it. I know glimmer is easy to come by, but Is there any way to sell the ship and get my glimmer back? I know scrapping it doesn't give you anything.

Comment: You should just enjoy being able to customise your loading screen.

Answer (score 5):

> **1.** You cannot dismantle a vehicle to get anything back; if you do you'll just get nothing and remove it from your inventory.

There is no way to sell the ship. Unfortunately, you will not be able to get your glimmer back.

Glimmer shouldn't be a problem after level 15 though, so don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get anything of value out of the ship once you have it.

Dismantling it just removes it, but does not grant any materials (whereas dismantling other items can give materials - dismantling a legendary glove can give 2-3 ascendant shards for example).

There is really only one useful use for glimmer, and that is in the form of buying ammo spawners.  Since there is a cap at 25,000 glimmer (which at level 20 you will hit frequently) you will end up buying a lot of ammo spawners to use, and they do come in rather handy for strikes / raids.

Vendor ships are rather easy to come by in end game. I frequent the vendor to see if there is a new or interesting one, but by now I rarely ever find any. If you end up with a ship you don't need, and want to hold on to it, there is always space in the vault.

Comment: One other useful use for glimmer is for having alts buy green armour pieces that they can wear while handing in bounties to level them up and get armour components when breaking them down. When I have fresh hit 20 armour components are a big bottleneck in upgrading my gear it seems. Its not a long term use but in my opinion a really good use of glimmer. :)

Comment: @Chris - I agree, alts are another good use for glimmer. Although, I tend to wait until I have a whole legendary alt set, and then level the alt in the crucible because it feels faster :P